# Search results vary within the same site for the same term

Tags: android, search, e-commerce

On the same site using the same search term and the same search tool, I am getting different results on a laptop vs mobile phone. Using this site https://www.barlowstackle.com in one of the tests I used the term "lure" on my laptop and then also on my android. The results returned were completely different even though the exact same search tool was used. It looks like the mobile results are actually not being filtered at all. When I just click the search glass on the desktop view without entering any search term the results match the mobile view.

I have come across articles on search result differences between devices on www searches with tools like google but am coming up empty for this scenario (site specific). Has anyone else ever run into this?

Thanks
Julie

Comment: Can u update which browser did you check with laptop & android mobile. i got exactly the same results in both mobile & laptop for term 'lure'

Comment: I just downloaded firefox for android and retested. I saw what you saw. It may be a chrome browser thing. Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a caching issue with Google chrome.